# Select table on currently viewed page (not currently selected page)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have set up a few custom buttons in Word that populate tables on a template. Here is an example of what I use to iterate through the cells of the second table:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Cell(i, j).Range
```

At first, this worked well for me because there was always one page in each template. This is no longer the case; now, it will be necessary for this program to be functional depending on what page is currently being viewed. Less desirably, I could have the user click on the page of interest and switch the code to use something like this:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Tables(2).Select
```

Word displays the page number of the page currently being viewed on the left side of the status bar. Example: "Page 3 of 7". So if the user was to click my custom button while they were viewing Page 3, I would want the program to populate the table on Page 3 - not wherever the insertion point currently is.

Is there a way to reference an object (e.g. a table) on the currently viewed page in VBA?

[Some coders](https://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html) seem quite adamant that this cannot be achieved, but I wanted to check with you guys before I go with the insertion point method.

Closing notes: there is not a consistent amount of tables per page, the contents/layouts of each table may vary, and the tables do not cross any page boundaries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Dim t As Table
Set r = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(740, 250)
Dim p As Long
p = r.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
    If t.Cell(1, 1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) = p Then

        t.Cell(1, 1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
        Exit For
    End If
Next t

End Sub
```

This will colour the first cell of the first table visible on screen irrespective of where the cursor is. You may have to fiddle with the x,y co-ordinates of rangefrompoint to suit your screen resolution

Comment: This works great, thank you. The only thing I would add is that if the coordinates happen to point to a header or footer, the table on the first page gets colored regardless of where you were viewing. I got around this by checking the story type at the coordinates' position: 

`If r.StoryType = wdPrimaryHeaderStory Or r.StoryType = wdPrimaryFooterStory Then

    Set r = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(740, 770) 
End If`